# slf4j, logback - refer to appender that is not referenced from any logger

Tags: slf4j, logback

I want to define SMTPAppender in the logger.xml file, but I do not wish to reference it from any logger.

Then when my application loads, I wish to programmatically add this appender to specific loggers.

However the "getAppender" method is accessible only from Logger.

Is there a way to work around this and get the appender without going through any logger?

Comment: I guess if you cannot get it from the context, a hack would be to link it to some never-user logger (say; this.logger.is.a.dummy.root) and then pull it from there?

Comment: This is the solution I am currently using unfortunately. Even though I don't control the logger.xml, I require the appender to exist in one logger so I can add it to other loggers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, I am not sure whether I have understand your problem or not but I can give a try :

```
    <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.OnMarkerEvaluator">
        <marker>MAIL_LOGS</marker>

    </evaluator>

    <smtpHost>smtp.gmail.com</smtpHost>
    <smtpPort>465</smtpPort>
    <SSL>true</SSL>
    <username>${username}</username>
    <password>${password}</password>
    <to>${email1}</to>
    <from>${from}</from>
    <subject>URGENT: ERROR NOTIFICATION </subject>

    <cyclicBufferTracker class="ch.qos.logback.core.spi.CyclicBufferTrackerImpl">

        <bufferSize>20</bufferSize>
    </cyclicBufferTracker>

    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout">
            <pattern>%date%thread%level%logger%msg</pattern>
        </layout>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

and add marker in your logger like

> Marker marker= MarkerFactory.getMarker("MAIL_LOGS");
>
> LOG.error(marker, "send this message");

Here all the logs which are marked as marker will get logged by SMTPAppender.

Comment: Funny how everyone have the `<!-- send just one log entry per email -->` comment in this code :) me too. Can you negate this? Can you state a marker to not send an email?

Comment: Sorry! That comment was by mistake. SMTPAppender get trigger by ERROR log level. As soon as it encounters any error log, it will send email.                    <bufferSize>20</bufferSize> tells how many logs do you want to send. Here it will send last 20 logs message. Your second question "Can you state a marker to not send an email", As I said "marker" will filter which error log you want to email, If there is no marker means no email notification.

Comment: Question still remains - can I make "send email" as default, and add a marker in case I don't want to send an email?

Comment: Yes!!! absolutely you can do that but sending every event of level may result in too many emails, cluttering the targeted user's mailbox and it also slow down your performance :

Answer (score 1):

Yes!!! absolutely you can do that but sending every event of level may result in too many emails, cluttering the targeted user's mailbox and it also hamper your performances.

Here are the steps by which you can achieve your task :

Step 1: Add janino jars into your classpath, you can download here http://janino.net/changelog.html

Step 2: Add following evaluator in your SMTPAppender:

```
<evaluator  class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator">
  <expression>
     (marker == null) 
  </expression>
</evaluator>
```